# jQuery trigger click triggers twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

I have a checkout form that uses php to load some javascript & html into `#Div-A` when the page loads.  The javascript binds a click event to `#Button-A` in the same div. Something like this:

```
<div id="#Div-A"><input type="button" id="Button-A"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Button-A').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'get',
        url: 'some/url/gets/called',
        success: function() { this happens on success }     
    });
});</script>
</div>
```

Afterward, `#Global-Button` is created and a javascript function binds a different click event to this second button which then triggers `#Button-A` to be clicked like this:

```
$('#Global-Button').live('click', function(event) {
    $("#Button-A").trigger("click");
})
```

The reason being that the contents of `#Div-A` can change (via ajax), so the second button acts as a global trigger regardless of which button or function happens to reside in `#Div-A`.

The problem I'm encountering is that for some reason if #Global-Button is clicked after page load `#Button-A` gets triggered *twice*.  If an Ajax event reloads the contents of #Div-A then all is well and the the trigger happens only once as it should.

I've examined the html within `#Div-A` before and after reloading via Ajax and everything appears to be identical.  There are definitely no duplicate buttons or functions anywhere as far as I can see that would cause two events to be triggered.

I know only a very little about the DOM and can only guess this has something to do with the order in which things are loaded and events are bound.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is always recommended to use 'unbind' before bind to make sure the event is not bound multiple times. In your case, there may be two possibilities -

1. '#Global-Button' click function is bound twice.
2. '#Button-A' click function is bound twice and '#Global-Button' is actually triggering the click once.

Change your code like -

```
$('#Global-Button').unbind('click').bind('click', function(event) {
    $("#Button-A").trigger("click");
})
```

and also -

```
$('#Button-A').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'get',
        url: 'some/url/gets/called',
        success: function() { this happens on success }     
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The second bit $('#Button-A').unbind('click').bind('click', function() { did the trick.  Turns out that repositioning the button using appendTo() was creating the duplicate bind.  I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this when shuffling elements around

Comment: There is also another option, you can have non-single result in your query. For example I encountered it when worked with checkboxes: frameworks generates hidden `input`, and while I assummed that `input[name="myname"]` will be unique it wasn't true.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `.live`. [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated use .on instead

Every time you click on #Blobal-Button you are biding an click event.So you need to off before use it

Use [**.off**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove event handler

```
$('#Global-Button').off('click');
$('#Global-Button').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#Button-A").trigger("click");
})
```

Comment: I'm aware of on() but despite the fact that this is good advice, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use

```
 $(".selector").on("click", function (**e**) {
  **e**.stopImmediatePropagation();//use to stop click twice or more
})
```

Comment: It's saved my time. Thanks

Comment: ohh whats with the **e** never seen that before?

Comment: just drawing attention to the parameter i guess?

Comment: for some reason in my case e.stopImmediatePropagation() didnt work but e.preventDefault() work thanks for the tip